# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: OSGI start

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I had referred the [osgi start bundle NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478920/osgi-start-bundle-noclassdeffounderror/23491751#23491751) but still, I was unable to get what is the error. Can anyone please help me out in it. I tried all the possible ways but I'm getting the same error still. What should be changed in the manifest file? I would be thankful if anyone can help me.

I got the same error as [osgi start bundle NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478920/osgi-start-bundle-noclassdeffounderror/23491751#23491751)

The code I had written is copied from the below site. http://www.programmersought.com/article/45465120/;jsessionid=1C5BE3ABEAF5D2D73A54018254A24E5D

I had compiled all three java classes(MovieLister.java, MovieListerImpl.java, MovieListerActivator.java) and created a jar using all of them with the below manifest file.

My Manifest file looks like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Movie Lister
Bundle-SymbolicName: MovieLister
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: osgitut.movies.impl.MovieListerActivator
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework,org.osgi.util.tracker,osgitut.movies;version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
```

I'm pasting the part of error which I got when I tried to start this jar in osgi console.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator osgitut.movies.impl.MovieListerActivator for bundle MovieLister is invalid
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:292)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandProvider._start(FrameworkCommandProvider.java:253)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandInterpreter.execute(FrameworkCommandInterpreter.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.docommand(FrameworkConsole.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.runConsole(FrameworkConsole.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.run(FrameworkConsole.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: osgitut/movies/MovieLister
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: osgitut.movies.MovieLister
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 19 more
Nested Exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: osgitut/movies/MovieLister
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:292)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandProvider._start(FrameworkCommandProvider.java:253)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandInterpreter.execute(FrameworkCommandInterpreter.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.docommand(FrameworkConsole.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.runConsole(FrameworkConsole.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.run(FrameworkConsole.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: osgitut.movies.MovieLister
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 19 more
```

Thank you

Comment: You seem to be following a tutorial but there is no way to know what's going on. Please describe in details what are doing, what is your environment, what is the exact error, when and where it happens. Please ask specific questions as opposite to generally ask for help.

Comment: At the bottom of your stack trace, I see `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: osgitut.movies.MovieLister`. Is this class in the jar file for your bundle?

Comment: Yes, it is present in the jar file.

Comment: From your stack trace, you are using a version of Java that is 9 or later. Are you using an OSGi framework implementation which is known to work on Java 9 or later? The changes in Java for JPMS required some understanding by the framework implementation.